# Flux collectList() on list of WebClient exchanges always empty

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I'm trying to execute a list requests using `WebClient`, then filter them finding the first one that succeed (if any) and return that. Or fall back to a default response if non succeeded.

The problem I'm facing is that when I call `.collectList()` on a `Flux<ServerResponse>`, the list is always empty. I would have expected the list to contain *N* number of `ServerResponse` based on the number of requests I issued earlier.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> retry(ServerRequest request) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(request.headers().header(SEQUENCE_HEADER_NAME))
            .map(URI::create)
            // Build a "list" of responses
            .flatMap(uri -> webClientBuilder.baseUrl(uri.toString()).build()
                    .method(Objects.requireNonNull(request.method()))
                    .headers(headers -> request.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach((key, values) -> {
                        if (!SEQUENCE_HEADER_NAME.equals(key)) {
                            headers.addAll(key, values);
                        }
                    }))
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(request.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())))
                    .exchange()
                    .flatMap(clientResponse -> ServerResponse.status(clientResponse.statusCode())
                            .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders()))
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(clientResponse.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()))))
            )
            // "Wait" for all of them to complete so we can filter
            .collectList()
            .flatMap(clientResponses -> {
                List<ServerResponse> filteredResponses = clientResponses.stream()
                        .filter(response -> response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                if (filteredResponses.isEmpty()) {
                    log.error("No request succeeded; defaulting to {}", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString());
                    return ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
                }

                if (filteredResponses.size() > 1) {
                    log.error("Multiple requests succeeded; defaulting to {}", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString());
                    return ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
                }

                return Mono.just(filteredResponses.get(0));
            });
}
```

Any ideas why `.collectList()` always returns an empty list?

Comment: `Flux.fromIterable(request.headers().header(SEQUENCE_HEADER_NAME))` -- don't know about your issue but you should not start your flow this way. Also you shouldn't use a `Flux` to trigger a series of `WebClient` `Monos`.

Comment: Could you elaborate why not to start the flow that way? And I'm guessing I will need to first construct the `WebClient` `Monos` individually, then chain them together with `.onSuccess()`/`onError()`, is that what you're getting at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems to me you have a confused requirement in that you want the `First` `Mono` that responds but you are trying to put that functionality into a `Flux` which is meant to process all items in the flow efficiently. `Mono` in Webflux is meant to create a flow that will perform a series of transformations on the item in the flow efficiently. Nothing in your requirement of testing a bunch of URIs for the first one that succeeds is what WebFlux is good for so I have to question why try to force that into the framework.

You might argue that a `Flux` is giving you better asynchronous processing but I don't think that's the case when it is a bunch of `WebClient` calls. `WebClient` is still HTTP under the hood and so each item in the flow stops and starts around `WebClient`. If you want to do HTTP asynchronously you should use a `ThreadPool` and `Callable`.

Comment: So, if I have a list of Mono and I want to do somethning when all responses are fetched and I use Flux.fromIterable()....collectlist().subscribe(x->myList.add(x)) it fails, why ?

Comment: Probably because you have a Flux of Monos which can't be correct. Use Mono.zip instead to process multiple Monos at once.

Comment: It's been three years and I'm more knowledgeable in Spring/Reactor and what you said makes perfect sense to me now.